# Data does not store in sharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am new to Android. I am using a separate class for storing data like user_name, mobile_number and IMEI number using sharedPreference and custom model class (User).

```
public class UseSharedPreference {
    private final String NAME = "name";
    private final String MOBILE = "mobile";
    private final String IMEI = "imei";
    private final String STATUS = "status";

    private User user;
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    public void storeData(Context context) {
        _context = context;
        sp = _context.getSharedPreferences("user_detail",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sp.edit();

        editor.putString(NAME, user.get_name());
        editor.putString(MOBILE, user.get_mobile());
        editor.putBoolean(STATUS, user.is_status());
        editor.putString(IMEI, user.get_imei());
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(context, "User Name : " + sp.getString(NAME, "")
                        + "\nMobile : " + sp.getString(MOBILE, "")
                        + "\nIMEI : " + sp.getString(IMEI, "")
                        + "\n status : " + sp.getBoolean(STATUS, false)
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the data in your user model, data is exist or blank...If data is blank then it will show blank so first check data in user model.
Preference code is correct, check your user model

Comment: Also, use either `editor.apply();` or `editor.commit();`

Comment: how did you try to get the saved data?

Comment: data exist, I have checked in MainActivity

Comment: sp.getString(Name,"");

Answer (score 0):

Use this class to save, delete and get data from Shared Preferences:

```
public class SharedPreferenceHelper {
    private static SharedPreferences preferences;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public static void initialize(Context con) {
        if (null == preferences) {
            preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
        }
        if (null == editor) {
            editor = preferences.edit();
        }
    }

    public static void save(String key, String value) {
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public  static void save(String key, boolean value){
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static void save(String key, Integer value) {
        save(key, String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public static void save(String key, Long value) {
        save(key, String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public static String get(String key) {
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }

    public static Boolean contains(String key) {
        return preferences.contains(key);
    }

    public static void removeKey(String key) {
        editor.remove(key);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public  static void setSPBoolean(String key, boolean value){
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue){
        boolean value = preferences.getBoolean(key, defValue);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Activity class:

```
SharedPreferenceHelper.initialize(getContext());

SharedPreferenceHelper.save(AppConstants.SAVE_USERNAME, userNameEditText.getText().toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Donot declare variables as final in this case. 
Because we cannot alter a final variable